# Azure Offline DataSync - Insert multiple records on single request

Tags: azure, azure-data-sync

I am using Azure offline data sync framework to sync mobile app data to server. But I am seeing huge performance hit. Time taken to sync 2000 records of data is around 25 min. When I had further analysis, each http request is taking around 800ms during PushAsync.

Can someone help me how to send multiple records as part of http request during PushAsync operation?

Comment: Which region is your server and mobile app client located. You need to consider the network latency based on the region. Also try to figure out if this is due to local bandwidth issues.

Comment: How are you sending the push requests now? Du you have a code sample?

Comment: // Sample code                                                                                     
 foreach (var audit in Audits) {
 await  SyncMobileServiceClient.DataSyncData.AuditTable.InsertAsync(audit);  }

await SyncMobileServiceClient.MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync(cancelToken);